# What is the timezone for central time in united states in node

Tags: node.js, date, timezone

I'm creating a bot manger web app that sets times for a bot to run. But my intended user is in Texas. He needs the bot to run off CMT. I am using node schedule to make cron jobs for the bot to run. I need to make a dateobj specifically in CMT time so the bot executes at the correct time every time. So I'm trying to create date objs in central time, but I don't know the timezone string for CMT.

Anybody know it??

Comment: Search engine right there in your browser bar.

Comment: Yea not like that wasen't my first try guy @tadman

Comment: Maybe that's because you're asking for something that doesn't exist. Do you mean Central or Mountain time? Do you mean GMT, which in practice is UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 'US/Central' for central United States from Indiana to Denver. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: `US/Central` is an alias for `America/Chicago`.  Use that instead.  See [the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Also, Indiana is mostly in Eastern Time - only parts are in Central Time.  Denver is in Mountain Time, not Central.  And "CMT" is not a time zone abbreviation that is commonly used anywhere, as far as I am aware.